# "Who is it" in Italian and Persian

Tags: comparison

Italians say: "Chi è?"

Iranians say: "Kié?" (کیه in Persian alphabet)

Is it just a coincidence that the spoken form of both is the same or there's a relation between the two languages in this aspect?

Fun fact: Even some Italians look like Iranians facially! and culturally of course.

Comment: If there is a connection, it probably stems from both languages belonging to the Indoeuropean language family. Compare with, e.g., Bulgarian "кой е?" (read as "koiè"). The original proto-Indoeuropean form of "who" is **kʷis* (from which the English form *who* is derived as well, although via a lot of non-obvious sound changes). Unfortunately I don't know enough about Indoiranic etymology to look at it from that direction...

Comment: Of course, كيه (kié) is the spoken form in Iran consisting of ki + e. ki separately is the spoken form for "who", and é is the spoken form for is. But the written form of "who" in Persian is كس (kas). And "Who is" in written form is "che kasi ast?" (چه کسی است؟)

Comment: As I said, the Italian *chi è* has a very transparent etymology through the Latin *quis est* all the way to proto-Indoeuropean. I guess the question is where the spoken Iranian form comes from, but unfortunately I don't know enough about Persian to answer from that side.

Comment: As Denis Nardin says, Persian and Italian are relatives, because of their common  Indoeuropean family, and there are many words that are similar in Persian and Italian, for example *padar* (padre)  and *madar* (madre), e molte altre. V. https://www.eastjournal.net/archives/66313.  But I don't know Persian, so I cannot say anything about Kiè, but a common origin is possible.

Comment: @DenisNardin It could be also a later borrowing - Persian apparently has many words borrowed from European languages, like *merci* (=thank you). See  [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persian_vocabulary#French_and_other_European_influences) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_French_loanwords_in_Persian).

Comment: @RogerVadim Merci and almost all European words came to the Persian language after the colonialism period. They didn't exist in the old times of Iran. But kiè existed in the Persian language from the old days.